# SwiftUI Move Text within HStack to next line

Tags: ios, text, swiftui, alignment, hstack

I have a scenario where some text within an `HStack` may need to be multiple lines. I would like for the text to extend into the next line so a user would see 2 lines both left-aligned.

Here is some base setup in my `View`:

```
VStack(alignment: .center) {
    HStack(spacing: 4) {
        HStack(spacing: 4) {
            Text("display name")
            Image("display image").resizable().frame(width: 10, height: 10, alignment: .center)
        }
        Text("blah blah blah") // This text can extend to more than 1 line...
            .lineLimit(nil) // so the text will be more than 1 line...
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
        Spacer()
    }
    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 32, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 16))
    Spacer()

    // more stuff here
}
```

So what happens here is that my text does extend to more than one line, but it stays within its own little box, it doesn't move into a whole new line so it'll be under the first text within this `HStack`.

Update:

I ran this code in a blank project. Here is a screenshot for a visual example. It is not displaying how I want it to.

The goal is to keep it aligned and then move the second line below to start where the display name starts.

[image]

Comment: This code works as you described. There is likely another limitation you are not including. Test it out in a blank project

Comment: @loremipsum I added to a blank project. It does not display how I want it to. I provided an image as an example.

Comment: ok so the issue isn't the two lines the issue is that you want the second line of your second `Text` to go below the `Text("display name")`, correct? If so, I don't think you can do that with an image in the middle.

Comment: @loremipsum yes, that is correct. I removed the image just to test but it gives the same result.

Comment: If you put a + in between the 2 Text and put them both in the HStack it should behave line a string

Comment: @loremipsum Hmm, ok. I have to go off of this design for right now though so I may just be out of luck...

Comment: I think the issue here is that you need to show how you want the view to look. The only thing you have shown is the view as it is rendering as a result of your code. And, it is doing exactly what you told it to.  You should review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).